# Put ads at the bottom of the page, android

Tags: android, admob

I am using the admob service which google provides to enable the developer to put ad's into their app. The app is displaying fine, however I want the app to appear at the bottom of the screen, as opposed to the top.

Given my below XML code, how would I do this?

Thanks for any help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
      <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="" >

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I am also using this java code:

```
 adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        //LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        layout.addView(adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
        .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Adview add the line `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to display it in bottom of the parent and also your linear layout is taking up entire screen space change the height to wrap content.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. The above does not seem to do anything, could it be something to do with my <PageViewer> taking up all of the height?

Comment: Yes, try setting the height of pageviewer to 20dp and check if adview shows up and also remove the weight.

Comment: hmmm, no this does not seem to do anything either. Could it be something to do with the java code I am using to access the ad's settings? Also, I am using a relative layout for the page...could this be a reason why?

Comment: Also your linear layout is taking complete space...you need to change the height of linear layout to match content.  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: Hmmm, no this did not do anything either. It is really weird, no matter what positioning's I put on it....it does not move one bit. Could it be something to do with the java code?

Comment: Dont see any problem there. Assign an id to the linear layout and in adview put android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayoutid"

Comment: No this does nothing either, this is really weird.

Comment: Do you have ads:adUnitId assigned a value.?

Comment: Yes I have assigned that value, the ad is just floating over content at the top of the page, it is not moving at all.

Comment: In adview change android:layout_height="wrap_content". If this does not work attach a screenshot of your screen.

Comment: This did nothing either sorry. I can't attach screenshots yet sorry, as I do not have enough reputation. The ad is basically at the top of the page, just floating there; it is covering up some content at the top. It is like it is set to floating position, so is never actually changing

Comment: I am adding pages to the pageView dynamically, could this be why. As it is loading the add before the page os filled?

Comment: Try the code in my updated answer now. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
  android:id="@+id/adView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="50dp"        
  ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
  ads:adUnitId="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. This does not seem to work, I need to use a relative layout...else the ad will not display correctly; could this be the reason why?